# Write a program to replace each string of one or more blanks by a single blank in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Description: The program should replace sequences of spaces and TABs with a single space.

Input: `Pointers         are      sharp           knives.`

Expected output: `Pointers are sharp knives.`

I am not able to get the desired output, I get modified output inside `replace_blank` but not in `main`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void replace_blank(char *str);

int main()
{
    char str[50];

    printf("Enter the string with more spaces in between two words\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", str); 

    replace_blank(str);

    printf("%s\n", str); //does not get change 
}

void replace_blank(char *str)
{
    char str1[50];
    int count, i = 0, j = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {   
        if (!(str[i] == ' ' && str[i+1] == ' '))
        {
            str1[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }   
    str1[j] ='\0';
    str = str1;
    printf("%s\n", str); //gets changed value here
}
```

Comment: `str = str1;` is wrong. Function parameters are passed by value in C. So `str` is a local variable in the function. Setting it does not set the caller's pointer value (though in this case it is an array and an array can not be modified by assignment anyway). One quick solution is to do `strcpy(str, str1);`

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to modify the `str` in place (ie without using a second string buffer).

Comment: @kaylum can you please share or write code, not able to understand

Comment: Replace `str = str1;` with `strcpy(str, str1);`

Comment: Nitpick: the way postfix increment works, you can simply write: `str1[j++] = str[i];`

Comment: Your code is  good approach but there are some problems:  you should protect against invalid input: `scanf("%49[^\n]", str)` or better use `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)` and test the return value; you operate in place and write directly to `str` with `str[j++] = str[j]` in the loop and `str[j] = '\0';` at the end; you only handle space characters, not TABs.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to learning C. Your observation that *"I get modified output inside replace_blank but not in main"* is correct.
As already pointed out in comments, the assignment `str = str1` does not work like you assume. There are two reasons for this.

First because the parameters passed to a function are passed as **copies**, e.g. if you have a function like `timesten`

```
void timesten(int value)
{
    value = value * 10;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    timesten(x);
    printf("%d\n", x); // 5, not 50
}
```

the function will only modify its local variable `value`, which has its initial value assigned from `main`'s `x` but other than the initialization those are two completely independent and unrelated variables.

If you want the function to actually modify the argument it is passed, then the way to do that in C is to pass a pointer to the variable instead, i.e.
the function parameter is a pointer to the type of the variable and the caller pass the adress of the variable.

```
void timesten(int *value_p)
{
    *value_p = *value_p * 10;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    timesten(&x);
    printf("%d\n", x); // 50
}
```

With that knowledge you could modify your program to

```
...
replace_blank(&str);
...
void replace_blank(char **str_p)
...
*str_p = str1;
}
```

however then you run into the second problem:

The `str1` variable is a function local variable that lives on the stack and its scope is limited to when the function
is executing. When the function returns, the memory it used will be freed and the pointer now points to an "invalid" location, i.e. that memory is considered free
by the compiler and will be allocated and used for other things.
(Also this would lose the reference to `main`'s `str` variable. Not a substantial problem for this particular code, but worth noticing.)

So there are two ways to achieve your intened behaviour of `replace_blank`, either by copying the string with `strcpy`
or by changing the function to modify the string it is passed directly instead of operating on a local `str1` variable
(like already suggested in comments by kaylum).

Of those I think modifying the string directly instead of using a copy is the best approach.

---

Maybe you noticed that I use postfix `_p` on pointer variable names. I recommend that you do the same. Now some people will have strong oppinions
on what is called [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) and detest any form of that, inlcuding using `_p`.
I agree that using `b` to indicate that a variable is boolean, etc is a horrible idea and you should not do that.
But using `_p` is beneficial since pointers have fundamentally different semantics than non-pointers.
Using `_p` helps [making wrong code look wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Although for char pointers you need to distinguish between actual pointer to a single char, e.g.

```
void init_separator(char *ch_p)
{
    *ch_p = ':';
}
```

(use `_p`) and strings (do not use `_p`).